# Error 1 while installing pip package (pycrypto)

Tags: python, pip, pycrypto

I've been trying to install pycrypto. After getting this error, I tried to uninstall python 3.7 and install 3.6 as specified by a thread somewhere. This didn't make it any better. Please let me know how to resolve this. I'm on Windows 7, 64 bit, Python 3.6.

```
    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -u -c
"import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\p
ip-install-lm9pf3lz\\pycrypto\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__fil
e__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__,
'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-0pd9vdl0
\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with e
rror code 1 in C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lm9pf3lz\pycrypto\
```

Comment: any particular reason you are not just doing `pip install pycrypto`?

Comment: If you are using `pip` to install and you got that error, look above it in the rest of the output. I get the same error output as you have above and the reason is most likely that above in the output it says that I need Visual Studio Build Tools installed

Comment: @AustinYates I am using `pip install crypto`

Comment: That actually is right, thank you so much. @AustinYates

Comment: No Problem - always look above where you see the error to make sure there wasn't an earlier reported problem and then handle the errors in order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also install via wheels, which usually include the binary so you don't have to compile.

https://github.com/sfbahr/PyCrypto-Wheels